# How to control desktop app windows with python

Tags: python, windows, desktop

I'm trying to make a python bot for [zoom.us](https://zoom.us/), but to join a meeting, zoom tells us to download an application and to join the meeting from there. Is there any python module like selenium but to control desktop apps? I found PyAutoIt, but is there anything better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't understand entirely what you're planning to do, but maybe [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the zoom app for desktop and use the 'pyautogui' module to automate the GUI of zoom app. here is a script that I wrote to automate mine. edit the positions of the app according to your machine

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

class ZoomOpener():
    def __init__(self, meeting_id, password):
        self.meeting_id = meeting_id
        self.password = password

    def main(self):

        # clicks on zoom logo in the task bar and opens it
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(550, 800, duration=0.2)

        # clicks on join button
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(x=550, y=317, clicks=2, interval=0.2)

        # types the meeting id
        pyautogui.typewrite(self.meeting_id,interval=0.06)

        # clicks the join button
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(x=690, y=487)

        # types the password
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.click(x=550, y=317, clicks=2)
        pyautogui.typewrite(self.password, interval=0.06)


        # clicks the join button
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(x=690, y=487, clicks=1)

        # final joining
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.click(x=900, y=590, clicks=2, interval=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    time.sleep(10)
    zoom = ZoomOpener('9656400024', '123456')
    zoom.main()
```